# Not allowed to load local resource electron-webpack electron-builder

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder

I have electron-webpack building a main, and renderer folder into dist as in the main example. The compiled code runs if I run a webserver in the renderer folder.

But electron-builder is not getting the files correctly. If I run electron-builder, I get the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource 
file:///Applications/my.app/Contents/Resources/renderer/index.html
```

My main/index.js contains the line:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
    `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html')}`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that:

```
mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'))
```